# タグを作成する基準はありますか (eg. N 個以上でタグを作る)

Tags: 討議, タグ

タグを作成するにあたって、例えば１個しか質問がないならば、それようにタグを作成するのはどうなのかな、という気がします。
ただそうすると、具体的に何個ぐらいになってからタグを作成するべきなのかなと思います。

どれぐらいの記事があれば、タグを作成し始めるのが妥当でしょうか。

具体的には、 Elasticsearch の記事が今現在２つほど存在しているのですが、これについてタグをつけて回ろうかどうか逡巡したので、質問しています。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[権限 - create new tags - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

既存のタグが存在せず、新規作成が妥当なタグであれば、たとえそのタグに該当する質問が一つしかなくても作成して良いと思います。モデレータには新規作成されたタグが一覧できるようですから、作成されたタグに問題があるようなら修正が入ることでしょう。

言語名やプロダクト名などの固有名詞は、タグとして作成することは妥当だと思います。

Comment: 最近作成されたタグはモデレーターでなくても一覧できますね http://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new

Comment: 新規作成されたもののその後複数の質問で使われなかったタグは自動削除されるので、この意味でも条件を満たしていれば自由に作って良いように思います。